# Where is the data related to "Pin to Start" stored?

Tags: windows-10-desktop, startmenu

I am trying to find out where the data is stored that indicates tile grouping, position, size, etc, when a user pins a tile to the Start Menu.

Looking to make adds/changes/deletions without user intervention, or right clicking the app tiles.

Thanks!

Comment: "Looking to make adds/changes/deletions without user intervention" - this is exactly why Microsoft obfuscated the Start and Taskbar pin settings: to _prevent_ programs from making changes like these to make sure that the user is in control.

Comment: Except this user isn't in control, as for some unknown reason the ability to make persistent changes to the app tiles is locked administratively by system admins.

Comment: The system administrator has control of the system. (The domain administrator has control of the systems in the domain.) If you don't like what your system administrator did, then negotiate with the administrator. If the negotiation fails, then get a new computer that is not under the control of that administrator whose policies you don't like.